# How to Access two elements in data buffer using pointers?

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, cuda

I have a code to copying data buffer with 1 x 16 for the output and the input.
I want to access the elements using pointer and arrange it in 1 x 16 x (2).
Let's say:

```
int n = 4; // size 
int* h_a_input;
h_a_input = (int*)malloc(n*n*sizeof(int));

//2 for loop to generate data for the buffer a with size (4 x 4) or in linear (1 x 16)
// ...
//...
//The rest of the code
```

So the buffer "a" will be for example

```
h_a_input =
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I will copy it to the CUDA kernel to do some computational processing.
To get this output: with ( 1 x 16 x 2 )

```
d_a_output =
1 2 3 4      5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8      9 10 11 12
9 10 11 12   0 0 0 0
```

I know the CUDA basics of launching `cudaMemcpy` etc.
But I'm stuck in how to get this output from this input using **pointers** to manipulate and access the indices in the **kernel**.
Also is it better to let the **thread** access two elements at the same time? Or to let each thread access one element?

Comment: You should `cudaMemcpy` from host to gpu device (with `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice`), then process the device buffer in the kernel, and then `cudaMemcpy` the result from device back to host  (with `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost`). This will be demonstrated in any CUDA tutorial.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [`vectorAdd`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/0_Introduction/vectorAdd/vectorAdd.cu) CUDA sample. It's very basic. If I understand correctly, you want to write each value twice. It is fine to do that with a single thread. Something like `out[i] = in[i]; if (size + i - offset > size) out[size + i - offset] = in[i];`, where `size` is 16 and `offset` is 4 in this case if I interpret your layout of numbers correctly.